# How to make a folder named as system time in ms-dos

Tags: windows, cmd

In ms-dos so far i am able  make a folder with only date but i want to make folder with time also

```
mkdir echo %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~7,2%
```

make a folder called

> 20150107

but i want to make folder with time also.
lets say my current time is 7th Jan 2015 4:03 PM

> 20150107 1603

How to do it?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/147515/need-leading-zero-for-batch-script-using-time-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try this:

mkdir %Date:~-4,4%*%Date:~-7,2%*%Date:~-10,2%*%time:~0,2%*%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%

You can modify format as you need.

Comment: in your format:
mkdir %Date:~-4,4%%Date:~-10,2%%Date:~-7,2%" "%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%

.